# Create 'DropDown' and 'Radio Switch' Cells within AngularJS Grid

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create an Angular JS grid that allows for certain cells to be drop-downs (Data comes from MSSQL DB) and certain cells to allow user input (Clicking to highlight). This user input then needs to be sent back to the MSSQL DB. So far I have the grid setup with pagination etc but editing the actual cells is where I'm getting stuck, i need the 'SFO' field to be drop down and the 'MFO' field to be able to take the user input.

Any help would be appreciated and if I've missed anything for the question just let me know. I am quite new to AngularJS so apologies if this is an easy task!

My code so far is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Client Tags</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="../CSS/InputToolCSS.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
```

```html
<body ng-app="uigridApp">
<div class="formStructureNxx">
    <form action="/action_page.php">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="select" id="BankerName" name="title">
                <option value="">Banker Name...</option>
                <option value="o1">Option1</option>
                <option value="o2">Option2</option>
                <option value="o3">Option3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        <fieldset class="form-item">
            <label class="control control-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="checkoption_label1" class="control-input">
                <span class="control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="control-description" id="checkoption_label1">Last Updated Details</span>
            </label>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="banner__body__content--left undefined">
            <p class="bannerDetails"><u>Client Tags</u></p>
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="uigridCtrl">
            <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="myGrid"></div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("uigridApp", ["ui.grid", "ui.grid.pagination"]);
app.controller("uigridCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75, 100],
        paginationPageSize: 15,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'Rel Name' },
            { field: 'Country Affinity', enableFiltering: false },
            { field: 'Client Name', enableFiltering: false },
            { field: 'Client Type', enableFiltering: false },
            { field: 'Residence', enableFiltering: false },
            { field: 'SFO', enableFiltering: false },
            { field: 'MFO', enableFiltering: false },
            //
            // { field: 'PE', enableFiltering: false },
            // { field: 'Char', enableFiltering: false },
            // { field: 'Fid', enableFiltering: false },
            // { field: 'SPV', enableFiltering: false },
            // { field: 'Pen', enableFiltering: false },
            // { field: 'NRI', enableFiltering: false },
            // { field: 'GRI', enableFiltering: false },
            // { field: 'UK/RND', enableFiltering: false },
            // { field: 'US', enableFiltering: false },
        ],
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
        }
    };
    $scope.users = [
        { 'Rel Name': "erferf Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "asdasd Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "Madhav Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "Madhav Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "erfefref Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "Madhav Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "Madhav Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "56h5 Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "Madhav Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "Madhav Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10},
        { 'Rel Name': "erg Sai", 'Country Affinity': 10, 'Client Name': 10, 'Client Type': 10, Residence: 10}
    ];
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.users;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the role of forms in client-side AngularJS applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload that sends the data to the server. Instead some javascript logic should be triggered to handle the form submission in an application-specific way.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#)

---

The `<select>` directive is used together with `ngModel` to provide data-binding between the scope and the `<select>` control (including setting default values). It also handles dynamic `<option>` elements, which can be added using the `ngRepeat` or `ngOptions` directives.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="singleSelect"> Single select: </label><br>
    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
      <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Is it possible to integrate this into an AngularJS grid so that the cell of a record in the grid is a drop down select?